# SQL Server Table Lockings/Blockings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the example below, assuming that TABLE1 contains 1million records;

1. `SELECT * INTO TMP_TABLEA FROM TABLE1`
2. `SELECT * INTO TMP_TABLEB FROM TABLE1`
3. `INSERT INTO TMP_TABLEC (COLUMN1) SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1`

Question;

1. Considering that the queries has been executed at the same time, do the TABLE1 will be locked? Or will cause blocking anyhow?
2. Does it significantly affects the execution performance of each query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server readers never block readers. So no, none of those statements block each other. Because despite they write to tables, the tables they write are different.

First statement will lock exclusively `TMP_TABLEA`, but it will put shared locks on `TABLE1` under the default isolation level.

Second statement will lock exclusively `TMP_TABLEB`, but it will put shared locks on `TABLE1` under the default isolation level.

Third statement will put exclusive locks (rows, pages or the whole object) of `TMP_TABLEC`. but it will put shared locks on `TABLE1` under the default isolation level.

Obviously it affects performance, as you are asking SQL Server to do three things at the same time. However it is faster to execute all three statements at the same time using three connections than executing them serially using just one connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Considering that the queries has been executed at the same time, do the TABLE1 will be locked? Or will cause blocking anyhow?

Answer: Yes, but shared lock(actually Read Committed locks) will be applied on TABLE1, which is released as rows are gettting read one by one. As it is a shared lock, it is non blocking lock.

2. Does it significantly affects the execution performance of each query?

Answer: Yes it does. But you can improve the performance al lot by using some kind of partitioning in the TABLE1. So, that it can leverage the multicore CPUs that you are trying to use. Also, make sure that you have set indexes for the TABLE1 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no write operation involved in TABLE1, blocking won't occur.

during read operation, Shared lock. which means no block.

during write operation, exclusive lock. which means block.

But definitely will cause slowness. Because the TABLE1 is sharing its available resource to 'n' number of operation.